# TypeError: Cannot create property 'transaction_date' on string '<'

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm currently learning React and I'm using Axios to get data from an API. I want the data to be presented in a table so I'm using a library which is working well. The app is working on localhost but it's giving an error on Heroku. All of the API links are good. I've defined the table in a function App and I'm calling it once there's some data in the transactions variable.

I'm getting this error:

```
react-dom.production.min.js:216 TypeError: Cannot create property 'transaction_date' on string '<'
    at home.js:122
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at J (home.js:120)
```

Here I call the API and I set state.

```
componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('/api/',{
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Token ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token')}
        }).then(res => {
             setTimeout(() => {
                        this.setState({ amount: res.data});
                        }, 800)
        })

        axios.get('/api/payments?type=company',{
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Token ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token')}
        }).then(res => {
             setTimeout(() => {
                        this.setState({ transactions: res.data, loading: false});
                        }, 800)
        })
     }
```

This is inside my return function:

```
render{return(
    {this.state.transactions.length > 0 ?
                    <App failed={this.state.failed} transactions={this.state.transactions} /> :
                    null
                  }
)}
```

And this is my data table function:

```
function App({transactions, failed}){
   const data = transactions;
   console.log(transactions);
   if(!transactions.includes("<")){
        Object.keys(transactions).forEach((key)=>{
        var date = new Date(transactions[key].transaction_date);
            transactions[key].transaction_date = '' + date + '';
        });
   }
.....}
```

Transactions:

```
[{…}]
0: {transaction_amount: 4324, transaction_date: "Tue Dec 15 2020 20:51:34 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)", available_amount: 4324}
```

Comment: Please provide a short example of the data contained in `transactions`.

Comment: 0: {transaction_amount: 4324, transaction_date: "Tue Dec 15 2020 20:51:34 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)", available_amount: 4324}

Comment: This is what transactions currently has: <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>..... more html.

Comment: I'm confused. You say it has this object structure, but then you say it has HTML. If it has HTML, then it doesn't have a `transaction_date` property and it makes sense why it's throwing that error. When you say `Object.keys(transactions)` and `transactions` is a string of HTML, the first key is `"0"` and the value is `"<"` (the first character in the string).

Comment: HTML is what it's returning when I console log it. It should be objects. I'm really lost as to why it's returning HTML.